# URL Rewrite only main request and ignore subfolders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have moved my Forum from vb4 (with vbseo) to vb5...

my old vb4 urls are:

```
example.com/123-threadtitle
```

new vb5 is:

```
example.com/category/subcategory/123-threadtitle
```

123 is the id of the thread.

my try:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)+-[^*]+ hxxps://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

it works but he rewrite the vb5 requests again and we have problem.

how can I set it to ignore foldered requests?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

is not working :-(

Comment: I assume `hxxps` is a bizarre typo in your question and not in your actual code? And I assume `/showthread.php?t=123` is the intended target - it's just that this is quite different to the new URL format described in the question. (?)

Comment: i typed xx because stackoverflow has denied domain posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ([0-9]+)+-[^*]+ hxxps://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
> ```

The regex (`RewriteRule` *pattern*) is not *anchored* so matches anywhere in the requested URL-path. The regex does not exclude slashes (ie. path segment delimiters) so will consume the entire URL-path.

If your old URLs are of the form `/123-threadtitle` then you would seem to only need to match the first path segment, which should naturally exclude "subfolders" (by which I think you are referring to the additional *path-segments* in the new URL format, not physical directories, which is what the *condition* you posted checks for).

Try the following instead:

```
# Redirect old URLs to "/showthread.php?t=NNNN"
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-[^/]+$ https://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=$1 [L,R=301]
```

This matches `/123-threadtitle`, but not `/category/subcategory/123-threadtitle` and *externally redirects* the request to `/showthread.php?t=123`.

This needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file before any existing rewrites. Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid potential caching issues.

---

However, for SEO purposes it may be preferable to internally rewrite the request to `/showthread.php?t=123` instead and then trigger an external redirect to the new URL (ie. `/category/subcategory/123-threadtitle`) in your PHP code.

```
# Internally rewrite old URLs to "/showthread.php?t=NNNN"
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-[^/]+$ showthread.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thank you so much.